Small leak next to water heater
I got a small leak near my water heater in the hot water side. Not sure how this happened but it’s leaking pretty slow (around a drop every 15 seconds), but I’m afraid that if I don’t do anything it might get worse. Does anyone have a suggestion on how to fix this by myself or the only option is to call the plumber?
Thank you!




someone did bad job in soldering

And then didn't clean up the flux afterwards, so it's been slowly corroding the pipe.

This happened due to bad soldering job.
This would NOT be an easy DIY job.
Best to call plumber to fix it
Unless you are experienced in soldering, you would use a torch and remove all, then clean the connections and re-solder them.

I agree "no hurry". But the leak will get bigger over time. Realistically, probably over a long period of time. But it started as "no leak" and progressed to "one drop every 15 seconds" and I would expect it to get worse eventually.

I disagree that it wouldn't be an easy DIY job.  If you are brand new to DIY or brand new to sweating copper, perhaps.

Yes it is a poor soldering job but, assuming you're handy, you might be able to repair it yourself without soldering by using a tee with shark bite connections. You will need to have at least an inch or two of play in the pipe connecting into the tee from the left and the one from the top. You'll still have to clean off the old solder first with a torch and sandpaper before attaching the shark bite tee.
The good news is the shark bite tee will be longer on all three arms than the one that's there now. That means that you can cut the pipes that the tee attaches to a little shorter, cutting away at least some of the solder that is next to the old tee. This makes the job of cleaning off the old solder a lot easier.
After you determine you will have enough play in the pipes to attach the shark bite tee, here are the tools you'll need:

Buy a shark bite tee, but make sure you have the proper size to fit the connections. Hard to tell from a picture but it appears to be 3/4" on the left and right, but the tee at the top could be 1/2". Be sure to measure each pipe.
Although it's not absolutely necessary, I would recommend you also purchase a shark bite depth gauge. They're not expensive and it will make the job easier. The depth gauge also has a reamer to bevel the copper pipe for a more secure connection.
You'll also need a propane torch, fine or extra fine sandpaper/emery cloth and a fireproof soldering cloth for cleaning off the old solder after heating and some heat resistant gloves (I use leather). You'll also need an inexpensive copper pipe cutter.

Here are the steps you'll want to follow:

You will need to drain the hot water from the copper pipes you are cutting. To do this shut down the heating element in the tank by turning off the pilot light (if gas), or turn off the power switch if electric.
Close the valve to the cold water inlet on the water heater. You probably should also close down the main to prevent any possible bleedover from cold to hot.
Open the drain valve at the bottom of the water heater and allow about half of the tank to empty. Opening upstairs hot water faucets will speed the draining. The hot water in the house lines need to completely drain down into the tank before you remove the old tee. You'll know it's drained by feeling the temperature at the tee. If it's hot or cold, there is still water flowing.
After the lines are drained measure where you want to cut the copper tubing around the tee. With shark bites I like to make two marks on each copper pipe.  Make the first mark with a fine point marker by overlaying the shark bite tee on to the old tee, aligning it with all three copper lines. Holding it in place make a mark on the copper pipe at the very end of each of the shark bite legs with your marker - this is not a cut mark - this will be the depth mark guide so you will know that the shark bite is fully seated when installed.
Set the shark bite tee aside. Now measure from this line toward the old tee to establish your cut marks. For 3/4" and 5/8" copper you will want to measure 1 1/8" and make your cut mark. For 1/2" copper it's 15/16". Be sure to measure toward the old tee.
Using your pipe cutter cut each pipe at the cut mark. Use the reamer on the pipe cutter tool to remove any copper burrs on the inside of each pipe.
Light the propane torch and heat any old solder on the pipe ends. Be careful not to place excessive heat on nearby solder joints. When the old solder begins to soften wipe it off with the fireproof cloth while wearing your gloves.
Next clean the ends of each of the copper pipes with the fine sandpaper being sure to remove any remaining ridges of solder.
Use the beveling tool on the shark bite depth gauge to bevel the end of each pipe. If you want you can also check your depth marks on each pipe by placing the shark bite depth gauge on each of the pipe ends. The depth mark you made on each pipe should barely show at the end.
Follow the directions for installing the shark bite by pressing the tee onto the end of each pipe. Depending on the amount of play on each pipe you'll have to determine the order of attaching each segment.
After the tee is in place you'll want to slowly open the main shutoff and the cold water inlet valve into the water heater checking for leaks.
Close any faucets in the house you may have opened and relight the hot water heater.
After that you should be good to go. I think this is a good project for a moderately experienced DIYer.

